# type mismatch in recordset definition in ms access

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

Here is my code:

```
Dim thisCase As Integer
Dim thisIssueID As Integer
Dim provCase As Integer
Dim rst As Recordset

thisCase = Forms!frmCases.CaseID
thisIssueID = Forms!frmCases![frmissues subform].Form!IssueID

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select tblissues.caseid from tblcases inner join tblissues on tblcases.caseid = tblIssues.caseid where tblIssues.IssueID = " & thisIssueID) 'CStr(Forms!frmCases![frmissues subform].Form!IssueID))
rst.MoveLast
rst.MoveFirst
```

Keeps bringing back "Type Mismatch" for the "Set rst =" line. I've run the recordset definition as a query (after removing double quotes and &) and it ran.

both fields being equated are the same datatype (ok autonumber and number).  But the query works.  I tried using + instead of & and that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Also, in the code, I generated the following string to use instead:

```
select tblissues.caseid from tblcases inner join tblissues on tblcases.caseid = tblIssues.caseid where tblIssues.IssueID = 24255
```

which works in a query, but when I put the variable containing the string into the recordset definition, I still get "Type Mismatch".  If I try to put single quotes around the value at the end, I get "Data Type Mismatch", so evidently it's some else than a data type mismatch.

Comment: Try declaring the variable as Long instead of Integer.

Comment: Couple suggestions. If you're expecting a DAO.Recordset you should declare it as such. Otherwise if ADO is the default, you need to add "NEW" to the ADO Recordset declaration. Also you can add a 'Debug.Print thisIssueID'  before running set recordset command to make sure you're getting what you expect,

Comment: I was being lazy, and I've got much more experience with the DAO recordset, I forgot the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [dbmitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2419128/dbmitch)
there should be explicit declaration:

```vb
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset
```

instead of:

```vb
Dim rst as Recordset
```